# Why getElementsByTagName()[0] return undefined

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to click a button on a webpage (YouTube.com). I want to click (trending) same pic (attached). But I can't do it and I already know that I probably need to use JavaScript. I try this code

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()
```

but said undefined.

[image: please see image here]

Comment: Either there are no `<a>` on the page, or you are running this in the `<head>` before the body has been loaded.

Comment: Are you saying you are running this in the browser console on youtube?

Comment: What specifically says undefined? How are you running the code? If you are running `document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click()` directly in the console, than it's not that weird, because the `click()`doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Ivar how click to trending same pic with java script?

Comment: @Taplar yes , i want click trending same image attach

Comment: `document.querySelector('#endpoint').click()` would more specifically try to target that link.

Comment: @Taplar Unfortunately it lists 21 elements with that same `id` for me.

Comment: @Taplar document.querySelector('#endpoint').click()     undefined

Comment: Right, because as already mentioned, `click()` doesn't return a value.

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('a[title=Trending]').click()`. Yes it logs `undefined`, but it should navigate to the trending page.

Comment: That specific link is the `[7]`th link on the page.  Inspecting the DOM and copying the CSS selector returns a fun value of `ytd-guide-section-renderer.style-scope:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > ytd-guide-entry-renderer:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)`

Comment: @Ivar thank you!it work